Show current gap while logging in AMPL+CBC solver
I'm trying using CBC instead the old dog CPLEX in my project to solve a large MILP problem. I would like to get the current gap as it's showed in CPLEX log but in the showed CBC messages.
CPLEX logging shows the following structure (using statement: option cplex_options 'mipdisplay=4";):

While CBC logs message structure is like this (using statement: option cbc_options 'outlev=1";):

As you can see, there is no gap information showed. For my research it is necessary to keep the tracking of the gap of the current best integer solution.
Is there an option that I unknow and it's not in the documentation to make this possible?. Thanks in advance!
I've read the AMPL documentation and try several options related to the gap state. Finally I arrived to cplex option mipdisplay=4 and cbc options outlev= 1 to 4. But none of them show the current gap.

CBC does not seem to have any option to really show the gap like CPLEX even with maximum verbosity. When it goes into branch-and-bound it may show lines like "Cbc0010I After 72000 nodes, 905 on tree, 267 best solution, best possible 266 (148.71 seconds)" but even in that case it does not show the gap value. More recent open-source solvers available with AMPL such as HiGHS provide a table like CPLEX provides.

CBC prints best solution and best possible once the branch and bound kicks in. You can calculate the relative gap from: |best possible - best solution|/|best solution|.
